# SEO: Deindex member profile pages?

Tags: seo, google, robots.txt, best-practices, noindex

I have a forum where users can register and automatically a profile page is created, like [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/53722/jonathan-meyer) in Stackexchange.

The problem with these pages is that sometimes users creates accounts at different sites with the same name and since we use a CMS these pages are very similar in content.

I have 200k indexed profiles, and in Google Analytics i see that these pages bring less than 100 uv.

Is there any advantage if i put a noindex tag on those pages?

Comment: I don't think this is really going to make a difference one way or another

Comment: You should always index the same content that non-authenticated users can see. You should only ever de-index pages if they are sensitive or they do not offer any user experience ~ but if that was the case then you should just remove the pages completely from the site nevermind Google.

Comment: I am not sure how easy it would be to do what you are suggesting, I assume that you are talking about all profile pages, even if you can selectively noindex the pages, that may be your best option. However, I would not do any of this unless you are sure there is a problem or you do not mind experimenting. As long as you have enough other content pages you may not be effected by smaller content pages. Google does understand that some pages will be smaller in content. As long as the site has enough pages with good value, Google can be rather forgiving.

Comment: I have finally included noindex,follow meta tag on member profiles, should i block using robots.txt that directory? These URLs doesn't provide any value and the main problem is that the CMS creates several pages for each profile like friends page, pictures.

Comment: Based on what info you have provided in that your profile pages directory not being a major part of the UX. I'd say if your going to noindex/follow, you may as well just block the whole directory in the robots and/or noidex/nofollow. This will help to gain back more crawl budget for more important areas of the site. As it stands w/ noindex/follow spiders are still crawling pages that you have indicated are of little value. Plus, if your user profiles include outbound dofollow links (submitted by users), they wind up leaking Page Authority / Domain Authority, so by blocking or noindex/nofollow